# Given a sequence of functions, I wish to prove the existence of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

So the problem is:

> Let $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $$f_n(x) = \frac{\sin(b_nx)}{1+(n^3x-a_n)^2}.$$ Prove that there exists $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ almost everywhere and in norm.

I think the best way to do this would be using the monotone convergence theorem, but I am not sure how to integrate the $f_n$/show that their integrals are bounded. Also, the way we defined $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is that there exists a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int |f_n|<\infty;$$ 
   $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) \text{ for every } x\in\mathbb{R}^N \text{ such that } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n(x)|<\infty.$$ Then $f\in L^1$.

I don't have much work done so any hints would be much appreciated; thank you!

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. Showing something exists and finding it are two different things.

Comment: Oops, didn't think I'd get ripped for a semantic error on my behalf. Thanks for the help, though :)))

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem does not seem to be a good approach.. In my opinion, the most natural thing to do is to consider $g_m(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{m} f_j(x)$ and show that the sequence of functions $|g_m|$ has a uniform upper bound, in order to use dominated convergence theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int |f_n(x)| \leq \int \frac 1 {1+(n^{3}x-a_n)^{2}} \, dx =\frac 1 {n^{3}}\int \frac 1 {1+y^{2}} \, dy =\frac {\pi} {n^{3}}$ where we have used the substitution $y=n^{3}x-a_n$. Hence $\sum \int |f_n(x)|  <\infty$. This implies $f=\sum \int f_n(x)$ exists a.e. and $f \in L^{1}$.

Comment: Hey cool thank you! Just a quick calc question then, how did you get that $\int 1/(1+y^2)dy=\pi$? Is this just a well-known value?

Comment: It is well known. It is also easy to prove by the substitution $y =\tan \theta$.